# querySelector() where display is not none

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I have a long list of `<li>` items I need to filter. I want the visible ones. Here's an example hidden one:

```
<li style="display:none;" 
<a href="https://www.example.com/dogs/cats/">
<img class="is-loading" width="184" height="245" 
</a><span>dogscats</span>
</li>
```

Those which are not hidden don't have a display visible attribute, they just don't have a style attribute at all.

This gives me the opposite of what I want:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.newSearchResultsList li[style="display:none;"]')
```

How can I select based on style attribute does not equal or contain "display:none;"?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This whole thing is kind-of hacky, but you could use the `:not()` selector to invert your selection. Beware some browser normalize the style attribute, so you will want to include a selector for the space that may be normalized in.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(
    '.newSearchResultsList li:not([style*="display:none"]):not([style*="display: none"])'
);

console.log(elements);
```

```html
<ul class="newSearchResultsList">
    <li style="display:none;">hidden 1</li>
    <li style="display:block;">visible 1</li>
    <li style="display:none;">hidden 2</li>
    <li style="display:block;">visible 2</li>
</ul>
```

If you want you could also select both these elements and any child elements.

```js
const selector = '.newSearchResultsList li:not([style*="display:none"]):not([style*="display: none"])';
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(`${selector}, ${selector} *`);

console.log(elements);
```

```html
<ul class="newSearchResultsList">
    <li style="display:none;">hidden <i>1</i></li>
    <li style="display:block;">visible <b>1</b></li>
    <li style="display:none;">hidden <i>2</i></li>
    <li style="display:block;">visible <b>2</b></li>
</ul>
```

Of course, these only work when selecting elements with inline styles.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, I prefer the simplicity of this answer but "Beware some browser normalize the style attribute, do you will want to include a selector for the space that may be normalized in." What does that mean? Negating just using not() seems to be the trick, but I'm scared of using now? Can you expand on the implications? Cheers!

Comment: @DougFir Some browsers will basically format the style attribute to insert the pages, either automatically when parsed, or if you ever change a style property. That's why the space should be included in the selector and my code has one `:not` with the space and one without.

Comment: This isn't working for me, apparently because descendants of `display:none` aren't displayed even if they are display:anything else.

Comment: @Michael You can select the children of those elements with the `*` selector.

Comment: Isn't the space selector to match children?  Also, specifying a selector such as `:not([style*="display:none"]) otherstuff` doesn't work because there are other elements in the hierarchy between the display:none element and the element I don't want it to find; the preceding matches its immediate parent.  The reverse would work (e.g. "child to parent" instead of "parent to child") if such a thing existed.

Comment: @Michael I added an example of how you could select both those elements and their child elements.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.newSearchResultsList li:hidden')
```

or (EDIT: Based on style attribute) Note that a simple SPACE destroys the selector. I mean: "display:none" can not be "display: none"

```
document.querySelectorAll('.newSearchResultsList li[style*="display:none"]');
```

or opossite

```
document.querySelectorAll('.newSearchResultsList li:not([style*="display:none"])');
```

Comment: `:hidden` is not a standard part of Javascript.  jQuery supports it, but not `document.querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: Tag is javascript and jquery-selectors, just answered >_<

Comment: Hi, your second line is the opposite of what I need! I need "does not contain". I tries using != but that did not work

Comment: @Rayon The `*=` attribute selector is native to the DOM API.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara — Even `IE7` supports that and I did not know that :( Wow!

Comment: Note: `style=xxx` attributes will only work if a style is set directly on the element.  It will not work if the element is hidden other ways (visibility or CSS).

Comment: Does not work in typescript in webpack application. Any solutions for shadow dom ?

Answer (score 4):

- Use `'.newSearchResultsList li'` selector to select all the `li` elements
- Use `Array#filter` over collection
- Use `getComputedStyle` to get all styles associated with element
- Return only those elements having `style` !== `none`

```js
var liElems = document.querySelectorAll('.newSearchResultsList li');
var filtered = [].filter.call(liElems, function(el) {
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
  return (style.display !== 'none')
});
console.log(filtered);
```

```html
<ul class="newSearchResultsList">
  <li style="display:none;">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/dogs/cats/">
      <img class="is-loading" width="184" height="245">
    </a><span>dogscats</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.example.com/dogs/cats/">
      <img class="is-loading" width="184" height="245">
    </a><span>Visible</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```