# How to filter getElement based on CSS property in JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code gets all the `tr` tags in `#mytable`:

```
table = document.getElementById("myTable");
trs = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

But if we want to get only `tr` tags whose `display` is not `none`, what should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [querySelector() where display is not none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813081/queryselector-where-display-is-not-none)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:visible` selector which is a jquery extension (https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) that allows seelction of elements based on display visibility.
In the following snippet - there are 3 tr's but the middle one is hidden with display:none. The console log targets the visible tr's and logs the number (2);

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  const totalRows = $('#myTable tr');
  const visibleRows = totalRows.filter(':visible');
  console.log('total rows: '+ totalRows.length); // gives 3
  console.log('visible rows: '+ visibleRows.length); // gives 2 - since one tr is hidden
})
```

```css
.second-row {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="first-row">
      <td>row 1</td>
      <td>row 1</td>
      <td>row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="second-row">
      <td>row 2</td>
      <td>row 2</td>
      <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="third-row">
      <td>row 3</td>
      <td>row 3</td>
      <td>row 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but you can do this...

```js
let tableRows = $("#my-table tr");

tableRows.map((i, obj)=>{
  if($(obj).attr('style') != 'display: none;'){
    // whatever you want to do here...
    console.log(obj);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="my-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>data 1</td>
            <td>data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
            <td>data 3</td>
            <td>data 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data 5</td>
            <td>data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
            <td>data 7</td>
            <td>data 8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data 9</td>
            <td>data 10</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution with VanillaJS

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
var noneElems = [];

elems.forEach(function (element) {
  if (window.getComputedStyle(element).display == 'none') {
    noneElems.push(element);
  }
});

console.log( { noneElems } );
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>Block</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="display:none">
    <td>None</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Block</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="display:none">
    <td>None</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```